# Docker command options --format not working

Tags: docker

I need docker ps output in JSON format. I've been trying:

```sh
$ docker ps --format '{{json .}}'
{}
$ docker ps --format='{{json .}}'
{}
$ docker ps --format json
json
```

When I try with specific parameters, it works: `docker ps --format '{{json .Names}}'` returns the name.

I have several machines. Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: The first and second options work fine for me. Do you have running containers when you run the command? What version of docker and the engine?

Comment: I have 1 container running yes, i can get the name with {{json .Names}}
Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d1802

Comment: it's an old version that I have, that's why on some machines (with a more recent version) it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker 1.12.6 is rather old and unsupported. It appears this was added in 1.13: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/20625#issuecomment-269989174

The current release is 19.03.5 and anything before docker-ce 19.03 is out of support (unless you have an Enterprise release).

Comment: But even in docker version 24 it doesn't seem to work. Bug or?

Comment: I just tested it, still works perfectly fine. Open a new question, and see [mcve] for details of what to include in the question.

Comment: Okay, but could you post your entire command here? Maybe there is something wrong am doing.

Comment: The command is in the question.